# Static Friction limiting equilibrium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

[image: problem]

My attempt at a solution:
27-Us*m1*g = 0
(M1+M2)a=maxForce 
Us*(m2+m1)*g=(m2+m1)*a

This problem also has two different answers apparently: http://www.brynmawr.edu/physics/courses/122/solutions/HW4.pdf
and 
[image: other solution]

How should I begin to approach this problem and which of the two answers is correct?

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, you can calculate the acceleration at the beginning of slipping (this acceleration is the same for two bodies) for the external force and the sum of the two masses. The acceleration of the "passive" mass (if the mass to which the external force is applied is "active") can be also calculated from the value of the friction force and the mass of the "passive" mass. So the answer (4/5)F seems correct.